# Inputtype textPassword for EditText allows whatspaces

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set EditText inputtype to textPassword, but it allows user to enter for example a space as part of their password.  Is there any way to prevent the user from entering a space  as part of entering their password?

Comment: wouldn't restricting the user to only valid characters reduce the level of security of the password field?

Comment: try as by code password_edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use trim on your password you should just put an inputFilter in the EditText and when the user presses the space button or every other character you don't want you should return "".
Example (overview):

```
text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
        // implementation of what you want or not
    }  
};
text.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```